# Telemetry client issue with Revulytics SDK

Tags: c#, api, sdk, telemetry

I am evaluating the Revulytics SDK and have some troubles initializing the telemetry client. I am
using C# and although I set the paths correctly, according to
http://devzone.revulytics.com/docs/v4/NET/sdk-configuration.html

I get “Config not created” error in the GenericReturn object I am using to collect the result of
the Start() method of the telemetry object.

```
string executionPath = "C:\Projects\RevulyitcsTest\Bin";
```

and then

```
telemetryObj = InitializeTelemetry();
GenericReturn test = telemetryObj.Start(true, false);
```

Put a breakpoint there, identify that folder and verify if the Revulytics binaries exist there.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the SDK binaries exist in the execution folder you configure? In order to make sure, you need to identify the location where the program executes, then verify if the correct binaries are there. From the looks of it, the binaries are not there.
i.e.

```
string executionPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

Put a breakpoint there or print that, and then check the folder and see if you've got correct binaries there.